# Two NumaNode0 on SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, cpu, numa

we encountered one mysterious problem. After adding 6 more processors to our database server, from 6 to 12, we are unable to adjust the processor settings on any of the instances.

We are now running SQL Server 2019 with 12 processors. The catch is after adding more processors, SQL created another NumaNode group, but with the same name as the previous one - NumaNode0.

I assume that's why I'm getting the error below when I try to change the settings. The production environment has 5 instances.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this easily?
Thanks !

**Edit:**

Output from sys.dm_os_nodes:
[image]

Output from sys.dm_os_schedulers:
[image]

And output from sys.configurations:
[image]

Comment: Did you try rebooting SSMS and/or the server?

Comment: Please add the output of `sys.dm_os_nodes` , `sys.dm_os_schedulers` , and `sys.configurations`  specifically for the processor mask.

Comment: What Edition of SQL Server are you using? "*The production environment has 5 instances.*" - 5 instances on the same server?...That's not a great idea.

Comment: I edited my question with the outputs from the sys tables. We also restarted the server and nothing happened.
The strange thing is that when I manually changed the affinity of the processors on a scale from 0 to 7, all the processors clustered under one NumaNode0. Of course, when I changed it back to automatic, the groups immediately split into two with the same NumaNode0 names.
ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION
SET PROCESS AFFINITY CPU = 0 TO 7;
They are not very large instances, two of them have databases with no more than one 1GB, but for some reason they have to be on a separate instance.

Comment: I also forgot we were using Standard Edition. I couldn't find anything on the web that could be a problem in this sense with the Standard edition. If I'm wrong, upgrading to enterprise could be the solution for us.